# Date Validation in Apex

Tags: apex, validation

I have a problem with validation date input on backend. I have a date input on frontend and when i fill it with invalid data and try to upload record, it will proceed but date will be empty.

What i wants to do is, when the data is filled with invalid values, it will return me this error

```
errList.add(String.format('Neplatne datum', new List<String>{ String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(rowIndex) + 1), fieldResult.getLabel() }));
```

Here is a part of my code.

```
Date dateValue = String.isBlank(fieldValue) ? null : Date.valueOf(fieldValue);
            String stringValue = String.valueOf(dateValue);
            if (!String.isBlank(stringValue)){

                //DO SOMETHING TO CHECK IF INPUT IS IN FORMAT dd.mm.yyyy

                errList.add(String.format('Neplatne datum', new List<String>{ String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(rowIndex) + 1), fieldResult.getLabel() }));
            }
            rowTransaction.put(fieldName, dateValue);
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [addError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm) method if you use a trigger.

Then you could do something like this:

```
for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
    if (condition is met) {
        c.addError('error!!');
    }

}
```